# MVC create function does not add created track to list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a problem with my MVC application. The application is about a tracklist where there is a function called create track.

I have created a dataprovider class which adds dummy data to a list. Then the list gets show on the page. The list itself works and it show the dummy data. Now i have created a create action in my controller like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            int hours = int.Parse(collection["Hours"]);
            int minutes = int.Parse(collection["Minutes"]);
            int seconds = int.Parse(collection["Seconds"]);
            Track track = new Track();
            track.Name = collection["Name"];
            track.Artist = collection["Artist"];
            track.AlbumSource = collection["AlbumSource"];
            track.length = new AudioDevices.Time(hours, minutes, seconds);
            track.Style = (Category)Enum.Parse(typeof(Category), collection["style"]);
            trackList.Add(track);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Now... When i start my application I click create. There i enter information for my track and click save. Now when it saves i go back to my list of tracks, but the track doesnt get added to my list.

My Visual Studio shows that the code has handled 2 requests without any errors. It just doesnt get added to the list.

I understand that i am not working with a database and i dont want to work with a database since its not needed in this excercise. I understand that the track will dissapear after restarting the program.

I have instantiaded the tracklist like this at the end of my trackcontroller.cs:

```
private static List<Track> trackList;

    public TrackController()
    {
        if(trackList == null)
        {
            trackList = DataProvider.GenerateDefaultTracks();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration and instantiaation of trackList ?

Comment: Try to declare and initialize trackList in the class controller as static if you just need a mock

Comment: @GianlucaConte Sorry for not adding this in my question, But it is declared and initialized as a static list

Comment: Can you show the `GET` function that displays the list of tracks?

Comment: your static is a property of the controller... as the controller is new-ed up on each request this is the wrong place for it. you should be able to verify this by placing a break point in the controller and it will go into the if null block every time.

Comment: Where did you defined DataProvider? It's a static class? or a dynamic property? Try to declare DataProvider as static.

Comment: @Seabizkit that's not properly right. Every request will generate a new istance of the controller, that's ok, but static properties aren't tied to a specific istance. They will survive to the entire application lifetime (for iis application that means that you must restart iis or restart the site to reset them).

Comment: @GianlucaConte sorry you are correct, brain was in another place...I tend to keep my statics... in a managed class for that responsibility. Anyway thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code follows the standard pattern, every time your `Create` function is called in the controller, a new controller is created.  If your object `trackList` is created in the constructor, then a fresh one will be created for each call to `Create` giving the impression that nothing has happened.

Comment: The problem is it is not created in the constructor. It is created at the end of my class trackcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Your data is stored in a variable. This variable is not public so it is not obtainable for the view unless you pass it along.

I suggest you store the tracklist in the ViewBag. this way it's accessible from the view.
Now I do not know how you implemented the tracklist so I will just give an example.

define when the page is created.

```
ViewBag.tracklist = new List<Track>();
```

after creating the track you put it in the viewbag like this:

```
ViewBag.trackList.Add(track);
```

You can access this data in the view or pass it along in the action index parameters like:

```
return View(ViewBag.tracklist);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never actually closed this, but it turned out my visual studio was corrupt. Everything worked fine as i did not received any erros. Reinstalling visual studio worked out.